# "redundant comma in array initializer" why it should be fixed

Tags: c#, coding-style, resharper

With ReSharper 6.0 I've received a new warning:

```
redundant comma in array initializer
```

for the case when I have a list of array initializer parameters with comma in the end.

What bad in that? Why I like "my" approach is that I often need to comment the latest value and don't want to bother with fixing those 'leading' commas:

```
    private readonly string[] _tables
        = new[]
              {
                  "users",
                  "user_account",
                  "user_budget_type",
                  //"user_budget"
              };
```

Please advise what is good in following that suggestion.

Thank you.

Comment: Disable the warning in question. As you yourself observe, it's completely useless. Don't let your tools redefine the way you work for no good reason.

Comment: This is why I don't use ReSharper - one of the reasons at least

Comment: @PavelMinaev warning are here to help you. Having a comma at the end might confuse a futur reader: Why is there a ending comma? Is it because there is an element missing? How can he know? Having a useless trailling comma is like leaving your left flasher on the hightway. Nobody can know for sure if you are ever going to change lane.

Comment: In `Options > Code Editing > Code Cleanup` you can also disable (uncheck) `Remove code redundancies` if you want those redundancies (commas, etc) to persist after a `Code Cleanup` operation.

Comment: In regards to @Drahakar's comment. From a code style perspective when using version control and diff - the trailing comma is there to minimize changes and easier see actuall differences in code. Trailing commas should actually be enforced - not discouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is in the text of the message:

> **redundant** comma in array initializer

What does it mean by that? Well, your code:

```
private readonly string[] _tables
    = new[]
          {
              "users",
              "user_account",
              "user_budget_type",
              //"user_budget"
          };
```

and the code with the inspection acted upon:

```
private readonly string[] _tables
    = new[]
          {
              "users",
              "user_account",
              "user_budget_type"
              //"user_budget"
          };
```

are **semantically equivalent**. That is, the CIL produced in each case is identical - there is no difference in behaviour. So the comma changes nothing and is therefore redundant.

Now, as to your question:

> What bad in that?

That's largely up to you. R# merely has this redundancy as an *inspection*, but it is you (through your acceptance of the default settings) that has it categorised as a *warning*.

If this construct is acceptable to your style, then by all means go ahead and change the Inspection Severity in R# options; but *in general*, the defaults for R# options are those that produce pretty close to the minimum amount of code necessary.

Comment: Good explanation of motivation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I agree that it shouldn't matter that there is a comma at the end, however, if you write your arrays like so, you don't have this problem.

```
private readonly string[] _tables
    = new[]
          {
              "users"
              ,"user_account"
              ,"user_budget_type"
              //,"user_budget"
          };
```

Comment: If you write your arrays like this, you will have a new problem: they don't look right. ;)

Comment: I would never, ever do this, but +1 for creativity :)

Comment: I did use that earlier (in C++ times), but in this case you will have problem when comment the first line. But ok, my main concerns is that there are no problems with leaving comma

Comment: Yuck. Also it now looks like there's a missing initial comma. So all you've done is moved the problem from the end to the start :)

Answer (score 3):

ReSharper is full of suggestions. Just like any other productivity tool, in the end it's up to you whether to act upon those suggestions.

For example, while the C# language allows a trailing comma or an empty control statement bodies (placing a `;` for a loop body), or even typing duplicate `;;` at the end of the statement. For all those things ReSharper will suggest you removing redundancies, because it's what it does - heuristically detects redundancies. If you know better, there are several ways you could "silence" ReSharper from suggesting it:

1. Temp. suppress the warning using special comments (choose the "Suppress inspection ... with comment" quickfix):

   ```
   private readonly string[] _tables = new[]
   {
       "users",
       "user_account",
   // ReSharper disable RedundantCommaInArrayInitializer
       "user_budget_type",
   // ReSharper restore RedundantCommaInArrayInitializer
       //"user_budget"
   };
   ```

or 
 2. Suppress this warning completely by selecting "Inspection options for ...", and choosing "Do not show" in the options.

It's all about choice and personal preference - you can configure just about anything you want in the tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress that warning,   Resharper is just saying that, just in case you care :)

Comment: I know, my question was: why ReSharper think that redundant comman is evil?

Comment: its not evil, its redundant, resharper will suggest to remove any redundant code.

Answer (score -1):

@Budda, Unlike other have said, this redundant comma  **is** eval!
In some browsers, for example IE8, this could cause the browser to misunderstand you and mis-create the object.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15522319/174944) for example, where the trailing comma caused the Highcharts library to stop working.

Keeping your code clean is not only a matter of easier reading and debugging. Even if you see your code working with this comma, it doesn't mean that it will be working the same with all browsers.

Comment: Valid, but that only mean that syntax style checks should be language specific: you should not apply R# rules for C# to JS code, etc.

Comment: I see now that your question was addressing C#. It wasn't specified in the question, but the example is clear.
Sorry.