# Highcharts not rendering in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, css, highcharts, lightbox

I have an issue that only seems to affect internet explorer 8.

I have used the highcharts.js script from http://www.highcharts.com/ to display data on my site however I have tried to display this data within a lightbox and have used the lightbox_me.js script from http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/

I will try to show the code I have used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
renderTo: 'analysis',
defaultSeriesType: 'bar',
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
},
title: {
text: ''
},
subtitle: {
text: ''

},
xAxis: {
categories: ['First Impressions', 'Politeness/Courtesy', 'Helpfulness', 'Speed and Efficiency', 'Reliability', 'Trustworthiness', 'Value for Money', 'Quality of service', 'After Sales', 'Overall Satisfaction'],
title: {
text: null
}
},
yAxis: {
min: 0,
max:100,
title: {
text: 'Overall Score (%)',
align: 'middle'
}
},
tooltip: {
formatter: function() {
return ''+
this.y +' %';
}
},
plotOptions: {

bar: {
dataLabels: {
enabled: false
}
}
},

legend: {
enabled: false,
layout: 'vertical',
align: 'right',
verticalAlign: 'top',
x: -100,
y: 100,
floating: true,
borderWidth: 1,
backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
shadow: false
},
credits: {
enabled: false
},
series: [{
name: 'Year 2012',
data: [<?php echo "$first_impression".","."$politeness".","."$knowledge".","."$speed".","."$reliability".","."$honesty".","."$value".","."$quality".","."$after_sales".","."$satisfaction"; ?>]
}]
});


});



</script>
```

As you can see, I have used php to insert the stats.

I then have the lightbox script:

```
$('#scores_button').click(function(e) {
$('#scores_container').lightbox_me({
centered: true, 
onLoad: function() { 
$('#scores_container').find('input:first').focus()
}
});
e.preventDefault();
});
```

This is the html:

```
<div id='scores_container'>

<h1 class='lightbox_header'>Areas of Performance</h1>

<div id='analysis'>

</div>

<p class='lightbox_paragraph'>We asked all repondents to score the business on it's performance in the areas above. This chart shows the average scores in each area.</p>

<a id='close_x' class='close sprited' href='#'>close</a>

</div>
```

And finally my CSS

```
#scores_container {
width:760px;
display:none;
background-color:#f2f5f7;
padding:30px 40px 40px 40px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
border: 1px solid #536376;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.6) 0px 2px 12px;
-moz-box-shadow:  rgba(0,0,0,.6) 0px 2px 12px;
box-shadow:  rgba(0,0,0,.6) 0px 2px 12px;
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
}

h1.lightbox_header{
font-size:22px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#536376;
margin-bottom:20px;
border-bottom:1px solid #cdd0d9;
padding-bottom:10px;
}

#analysis{
width:680px;
height:400px;
}

p.lightbox_paragraph, p.lightbox_paragraph_first{
font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight:700;
font-style:italic;
color:#536376;
border-top:1px solid #cdd0d9;
padding-top:10px;
}
```

This code works in all browsers I have tested but internet explorer. Internet explorer 8 is the browser that I have been using whilst trying to find a solution.

Please see this screenshot of how it appears in ie8:

[image: Internet Explorer 8]

And how it appears in Google Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome]

My thoughts are that maybe it is my css causing the problem but no matter what I try I can't seem to get the chart to display. The chart container is also not centered vertically within the browser window but this is something I can work on once I get the chart to render. Any help would be much appreciated.

I know it's not a particularly well built site as I am only learning but please see the following link to the site itself, if it will help: http://www.bbg.im/development

The error is occurring on the profile pages when the chart icon is clicked.

I also am experiencing the same/similar issue with pie charts and google maps in the same lightbox script.

Many thanks.

Comment: where is click than show lightbox ...

Comment: @Rohit Azad Hello. Sorry but I'm not sure what you are asking me. I have a div with the id #scores_button which, when clicked initiates the lightbox_me script.

Comment: I can see that you have errors in IE, could you use [this](http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.src.js) lib and copy error from IE ?

Comment: @PawełFus I will try that now. Do I just replace my highcharts library with the one you have provided?

Comment: Yes, it is the same library just a full source code - it is easier to debug. However, if you have extra comma in your code - it won't work.

Comment: @PawełFus Ok great, thanks. I will do that after I figure out where the comma is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just viewed the source of the HTML file and surprised to see the extra comma in the array.

`series: [{`
`name: 'Year 2012',`
`data: [95,100,95,95,95,100,80,90,93,]`
`}]`

Could you please remove the trailing comma at the end of the data array. i.e. the data array should render like this.

`series: [{`
`name: 'Year 2012',`
`data: [95,100,95,95,95,100,80,90,93]`
`}]`

Comment: Good spot! I will try to figure out where that comma is coming from now. It should not be there.

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much. It turned out to be a misnamed variable in my php that was not completing the series of data. This meant there was a comma appearing at the end as the last piece of data.